# Simple code analyzer

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, code-analysis

Need a simple code analyzer to see if I am forgetting to free objects and classes, or to see if I am releasing them to many times.

Comment: Craig's answer is probably the best you're going to get.  This isn't an issue that can be solved by a simple code analyzer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is built into Delphi's memory manager ([FastMM](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33416)). Set `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` true. You can also use the "full debug" version of the memory manager for [more detailed checks and information](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/).

Answer (score 4):

The Pascal Analyzer from [Peganza](http://www.peganza.com) does a static analysis of your code.

Answer (score 1):

AQTime from [Automated QA](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/) is pretty much the defacto standard tool in the Delphi World for profiling for memory leaks (and perf of course)

Another option is a static analysys tool, the only one I know of that supports Delphi is Understand from [SciTools](http://www.scitools.com/) it's pretty expensive though.

Comment: Understand 2.6 as of 1/9/2012 floating license: $1995
AQtime Pro floating license: $1899

Answer (score 1):

Simplest tool I've ever used for memory leak checking is MemCheck.

http://v.mahon.free.fr/pro/freeware/memcheck/